# Why does a summation cancel out leaving only the constant?

Tags: statistics, summation

A mean of a linear function Y is derived as follows:

$ Y = aX + b $

$ E[Y] = \sum_{x}(ax+b)p_X(x) = a\sum_{x}xp_X(x) + b\sum_{x}p_X(x) = aE[X] +b$

So how does the sum in $  b\sum_{x}p_X(x)$ disappear leaving only $b$ in the last step? There still seems to be a function of $x$ there.

Comment: The sum takes value $1$. The $x$ is an index here. Not an argument of a function

Comment: @drhab the $ pX(x) $ is a function, but it sums up to $1$, since it is the probability mass function! That makes sense. Thanks. If you'd add that as an answer I'd accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are dealing with a discrete random variable $X$ and $p_X(x):=\mathsf P(X=x)$.

In the sum $\sum_xP_X(x)$ the $x$ ranges over the countable set of values that $X$ can take so that: $$\sum_xP_X(x)=1$$